# Does an algorithm exist that finds the product of a n*n matrix in less than n^3 iteration?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I read that there is an algorithm that can calculate the product of a matrix in n^(2.3) complexity, but was unable to find the algorithm.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%E2%80%93Winograd_algorithm

Comment: I guess you mean "n*n matrix" in the title rather than "2*2 matrix"?

Comment: Just to point out that the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm, although slower at 2.807, is reasonably understandable, and could conceivably be used in practice.

Comment: Strassen's algorithm has some numerical instability but is cool at 8k x 8k but also needs more ram .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There have been several algorithms found for matrix multiplication with a big O less than n^3. But here's one of the problems with making conclusions based on big O notation. It only gives the limiting behaviour as n goes to infinity. In this case a more useful metric is the total time complexity which includes the coefficients and lower order terms.

For the general algorithm the time complexity could be An^3 + Bn^2 +...

For the case of the [Coppersmith-Winograd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%E2%80%93Winograd_algorithm) algorithm the coefficient for the n^2.375477 term is so large that for all practical purposes the general algorithm with O(n^3) complexity is faster.

This is also true for the [Strassen Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) as well if it's used on single elements. However,
there is a [paper](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/257719351_Effective_Implementation_of_DGEMM_on_Modern_Multicore_CPU/links/00b49529dfadea3a1f000000) which claims that using a hybrid algorithm which uses the Strassen Algorithm for matrix blocks down to some limit and then switches to the O(n^3) algorithm is faster for large matrices.

So although there exists algorithms which have a smaller time complexity the only one that is useful which I'm aware of is the Strassen algorithm and that's only for large matrices (whatever large means).

Edit: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Algorithms_for_efficient_matrix_multiplication) actually has a nice summary of the algorithms for matrix multiplication. Here is plot from that same link showing the reduction in omega for the different algorithms vs. the year they were discovered.

[image]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#mediaviewer/File:Bound_on_matrix_multiplication_omega_over_time.svg

Answer (score 2):

The [Strassen Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) is able to multiply matrices with an asymptotic complexity smaller than O(n^3).

Answer (score 1):

Coppersmith–Winograd algorithm calculates the the product of a NxN matrix in O(n^{2.375477}) asymptotic time.

Comment: Yes, but for all practical purposes it would be much slower than the O(n^3) algorithm because the constant in front of the n^2.375477 term is much much larger than the one in from of the n^3 term. The asymptotic time complexity can be misleading.